# Trouble Proving that if $f : A \rightarrow B \text{ then } I_{B} \circ f=f$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

> Proving that 
>    if $f : A \rightarrow B \text{ then } I_{B} \circ f=f$

My problem with this question is that I do not know how one derives the theory in order to get the correct answer. I will attempt to break down what I know in order to solve this enigma.

I know that $f: A \rightarrow B $ means that $ y= f(x)$ when $(x,y) \in f$.

I also know that two functions are equal when. Dom($f$)= Dom($g$) and $\forall \;$$x \in Dom(f), f(x) = g(x)$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use definition of function as relation, at least not directly. Composition of functions is in fact composition of relations that turns out to be a function as well.

$f\colon A\to B$ and $I_B\colon B\to B$, so $I_B\circ f\colon A\to B$ and we have $$(I_B\circ f)(x) = I_B(f(x)) = f(x),\ \forall x\in A\implies I_B\circ f = f$$

Comment: Is that all one truly needs to show to prove this question? Is their more?

Comment: @LittleJon That is all you need. Function composition has a simple definition which directly lends itself to the answer.

Comment: @LittleJon, yes. You wrote it yourself, $f = g \iff f(x) = g(x),\ \forall x\in Dom(f) = Dom(g)$. Technically, you do have to verify that codomains are equal as well (which you didn't write in your definition).

Comment: So essentially we take the definition of $ f \circ g = f(g(x))$ and we apply it to this problem. But we add a bit more notation so that it holds.

Comment: @LittleJon, well pretty much this is how any proof works :)

Answer (score 1):

We know that $I_B: B \to B = x \mapsto x$.

$I_B \circ f = x \mapsto I_B(f(x)) = x \mapsto f(x) = f$.